# Rails Routes adding '.' to nested resource show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using some nested resources right now - users have many manufacturers, and manufacturers have many lines. I'm able to access the line-show view just fine by typing in what the URL would be manually, because it looks like /manufacturer/37/lines/5. But when I'm looking at the manufacturer/37/lines page, and I hover over the 'show' link for the individual line, it tries to stuff a period into the URL near the end, and when I click on it, it goes nowhere. Like, /manufacturer/37/lines.5 which doesn't seem to be a valid URL. Can someone help me out here?

routes.rb

```
  resources :manufacturers do
    resources :lines
  end

  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"

  get "about" => "pages#about"

  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', :via => "get"
  match '/users', :to => 'users#index', :as => "all_users", :via => "get"
  match '/users/:name' => 'users#show', via: :get, as: :public_profile
```

rake routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                              Controller#Action
      manufacturer_lines GET    /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines(.:format)          lines#index
                         POST   /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines(.:format)          lines#create
   new_manufacturer_line GET    /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/new(.:format)      lines#new
  edit_manufacturer_line GET    /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/:id/edit(.:format) lines#edit
       manufacturer_line GET    /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/:id(.:format)      lines#show
                         PATCH  /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/:id(.:format)      lines#update
                         PUT    /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/:id(.:format)      lines#update
                         DELETE /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/lines/:id(.:format)      lines#destroy
           manufacturers GET    /manufacturers(.:format)                                 manufacturers#index
                         POST   /manufacturers(.:format)                                 manufacturers#create
        new_manufacturer GET    /manufacturers/new(.:format)                             manufacturers#new
       edit_manufacturer GET    /manufacturers/:id/edit(.:format)                        manufacturers#edit
            manufacturer GET    /manufacturers/:id(.:format)                             manufacturers#show
                         PATCH  /manufacturers/:id(.:format)                             manufacturers#update
                         PUT    /manufacturers/:id(.:format)                             manufacturers#update
                         DELETE /manufacturers/:id(.:format)                             manufacturers#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                 devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                 devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                            devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                           devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                 devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                                                        pages#home
                   about GET    /about(.:format)                                         pages#about
                         GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                     users#show
               all_users GET    /users(.:format)                                         users#index
          public_profile GET    /users/:name(.:format)                                   users#show
```

app/views/index/lines.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing lines</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @lines.each do |line| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= line.name %></td>
        <td><%= line.manufacturer_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', manufacturer_lines_path(line.manufacturer, line) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_manufacturer_line_path(line.manufacturer, line) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', manufacturer_lines_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use singular `line`, not plural `lines`:

```
manufacturer_line_path(line.manufacturer, line)
```

UPDATE:

Your destroy link looks fishy as well - it should be the same url as for the show action.

Comment: Thank you very much. My destroy link seems to work, but I'll keep that in mind in case it starts to give me problems.